# MySQL get records what have max value

Tags: mysql

This is my table named period.

```
id | year | month
222 | 2014 | 2
345 | 2013 | 5
33 | 2014 | 1
224 | 2014 | 2
```

I want get only id what have latest month (2014-02). Result should be 222, 224.

I wrote following query.

```
SELECT id, MAX(year*100 + month) FROM period
```

But it is returning following result. 
222| 201402

How can i get my result

Comment: Why do you need **only** the ID? What's wrong with it including the month?

Comment: what is the reason for down vote.

Comment: I don't know, didn't downvote.

Comment: @BenM sorry. it is not for you. I want get id for join with another table

Comment: Upvotes and downvotes are almost arbitrary in SO. Don't take it personally.

Comment: @Strawberry no. I didn't get it personally. But i wanted to know the reason because i could explain my question again with another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM period x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT year
            , month 
         FROM period 
        ORDER 
           BY year DESC
            , month DESC 
        LIMIT 1
     ) y 
    ON y.year = x.year 
   AND y.month = x.month;
```

Comment: Incidentally, if it was me, I'd try to find a way of storing the dates as dates - e.g. '2014-02-01'

Answer (score -1):

You should you the following query:---

```
SELECT id FROM period where year=(SELECT max(year) from period) and month=(SELECT max(month) from period);
```

Comment: Er, no. Think about it.

Comment: you checked year with 2014 and month with 5. I want 2014 02